# Is there a way to customize in view what will_paginate outputs on the page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, will-paginate

In my view..

```
<%= will_paginate @received_messages %>
```

renders..

```
← Previous 1 2 Next →
```

on the page. Is there a way to pass some options to that to customize the output? Like just page numbers or just next/previous page links (if there's any next/previous page) etc. Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can help you: [Module: WillPaginate::ViewHelpers](http://rubydoc.info/gems/will_paginate/2.3.15/WillPaginate/ViewHelpers#will_paginate-instance_method)